# How to convert HashMap.getKey() to Int

Tags: java, foreach, hashmap

I have a HashMap which stores Attendance information. I just want to convert the Key to Int and check for condition.

Below is my code:

```
import java.util.*;

public class HashClass {

    public static void main(String args[]) {

        HashMap<Integer, String> attendanceHashMap = new HashMap<Integer, String>();
        attendanceHashMap.put(1, "John");
        attendanceHashMap.put(2, "Jacob");
        attendanceHashMap.put(3, "Peter");
        attendanceHashMap.put(4, "Clara");
        attendanceHashMap.put(5, "Philip");

        for(HashMap.Entry m:attendanceHashMap.entrySet()){
            if(Integer.valueOf((int)m.getKey())<3) break;
            System.out.println(m.getKey()+" "+m.getValue());
        }
    }
}
```

I want to print like this

```
3 Peter
4 Clara
5 Philip
```

I tried these methods:

```
 - (int)m.getKey() : not working
 - Integer.valueOf((int)m.getKey()) : not working
 - Integer.valueOf(m.getKey()) : not working
```

How this can be achieved ?

Comment: The key on this code is already an integer. What is not working ?

Comment: Why are you even doing that conversion in the `if` statement? You can just do: `m.getKey().intValue();` that will return the `int` representation of the number, opposed to the `Integer` value...

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You are saying:

```
if(Integer.valueOf((int)m.getKey())<3) break;
```

In other words, if the first key you encounter happens to be smaller than three, you terminate the loop, hence print nothing. Most probably, you want to use `continue` instead, to process the next entry:

```
for(HashMap.Entry m:attendanceHashMap.entrySet()){
    if(Integer.valueOf((int)m.getKey())<3) continue;
    System.out.println(m.getKey()+" "+m.getValue());
}
```

But note that the type conversions are obsolete. Just add the missing type arguments to the entry:

```
for(HashMap.Entry<Integer,String> m:attendanceHashMap.entrySet()){
    if(m.getKey()<3) continue;
    System.out.println(m.getKey()+" "+m.getValue());
}
```

But it might be clearer to make the print statement conditional instead of using loop control:

```
for(HashMap.Entry<Integer,String> m:attendanceHashMap.entrySet()){
    if(m.getKey()>=3) {
        System.out.println(m.getKey()+" "+m.getValue());
    }
}
```

As a side note, the order of the printed entries is not guaranteed. If you want to print the entries in insertion order, use a `LinkedHashMap`:

```
HashMap<Integer, String> attendanceHashMap = new LinkedHashMap<>();
attendanceHashMap.put(1, "John");
attendanceHashMap.put(2, "Jacob");
attendanceHashMap.put(3, "Peter");
attendanceHashMap.put(4, "Clara");
attendanceHashMap.put(5, "Philip");
// printing code follows...
```

And just for completeness, the Java 8 solution:

```
attendanceHashMap.forEach((k,v) -> { if(k>=3) System.out.println(k+" "+v); });
```

Answer (score 2):

Your first problem is that you are using raw `Entry` type. Replace it with

```
for(HashMap.Entry<Integer, String> m: ...)
```

Now `m.getKey()` will have an `Integer` type which can be converted to `int` implicitly without any problems: `if(m.getKey()<3)`.

Another problem is that you are using `break` instead of `continue`. Write

```
if(m.getKey()<3) continue;
```

The whole fixed loop:

```
for(HashMap.Entry<Integer, String> m:attendanceHashMap.entrySet()){
    if(m.getKey()<3) continue;
    System.out.println(m.getKey()+" "+m.getValue());
}
```

Never use rawtypes. It's just a compatibility remnant.

Comment: Edit your question with more explanation about why he don't have to cast and convert. It can be usefull for lots of person.

Answer (score 0):

you mean  you dont want to show the entries which key < 3 ,I think when you run this code  you will get nothing because when key = 1 ,key < 3 = true and the loop break, they won`t continue you can try  continue instead of break